# Android Multiple Scrolling Views

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I need to have a dynamically set grid of images surrounded by a scalable image. Both of these views need to scroll concurrently.

Attempt 1:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<GridView />
<ScrollView>
<ImageView />
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This however only has the ImageView scrollable.

Attempt 2:

```
<RelativeLayout>
<GridView android:background="@drawable/img"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I switch to putting the image as the gridview's background the gridview scrolls, but the image does not scale with the scroll, rather it just fills the whole screen.

I have looked through other posts and have seen the ExpandableGridView proposal, but I would like to stay away from a hack that would take up a lot of memory on each scroll since I am displaying a lot of thumbnail images.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I feel like a picture would be worth 1000 lines of code here.

Comment: An example: A chessboard that has a gradient border around it. Except in mine case the grid is dynamic.

Comment: @kcoppock Is right. A picture would really help us understand what you're talking about. However, I think I might understand what you're talking about. Take a look at the answer that I have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you have a `GridView` that displays a bunch of thumbnails and you have a background that you're wanting to scroll with the GridView, right?

If so, you can't (at least I don't think you can) accomplish that with two scrollable views. The system has no way of differentiating which view the user is trying to scroll. If you really want to have the background scroll, your best bet would be to use the same method that is used in scrolling videos games.

The way that most scrolling games work is by scrolling a long image or cycling between two images and creating a scrolling simulation when the user "scrolls." If you'd like to see how this works, check out this [video game tutorial](http://www.kilobolt.com/day-5-background-and-sprites.html). It should give you a basic idea of how to go about creating a scrolling simulation.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have a gridview and a background that I would like to scroll together. 

So you are saying that you think I should have the background image in a scrollview and then populate the contents of the gridview according to the location the user has scrolled to?

Comment: Well, sort of. What I mean is that you should have a `GridView` in the foreground that contains all of your thumbnail images. Then, in the background, you should have a really long image that automatically scrolls when the user scrolls the `GridView`. I think that you could accomplish this with a `ScrollView` and `setFocusable(false)` then manually scroll the ScrollView when the user scrolls. Please note that I'm note quite sure about using a ScrollView to accomplish this as I haven't tried it. The basic idea is: allow the user to scroll the GridView with the thumbnails, but scroll the

Comment: ScrollView manually in your code. I hope that makes sense. :)

Comment: I tried what you said and this is the result: you had the right idea, but I couldn't stop scrolling by just setting setFocusable(false) on the ScrollView. I instead extended a ScrollView and locked scrolling in the ScrollView's onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ya, like I said, I wasn't one hundred percent sure about that method because I've haven't had to use it so far. Glad you got it working though. Please don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it answered your question.